# Regex for selecting text

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, quotes

I need to select text with double quotes and count of double quotes must be divideable by 2 or zero.
Example input:

```
Starting
blahaapvi "Starting + Ending"
asfg "Ending"
Ending
```

I now have this: `Starting(.*)Ending`
... but I don't want to match text in quotes. Anybody please help me.

Comment: When you say "quotes", do you mean double quotes?

Comment: Could you please specify the count of what should be divisible by two.

Comment: There is actually a very good resource for regexes: http://www.regexpal.com, where you can try out expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find a text that has balanced double quotes

```
^Starting([^"]*"(?<txt>[^"]*)"[^"]*)*Ending$
```

Here is the explanation

`^Starting`   The pattern at the very beginning of the text.

`[^"]*`              Any number of charactes not including a double quote.

`"(?<txt>[^"]*)"`    Text included in double quotes captured in a capture named "txt".

`[^"]*`              Again any number of charactes not including a double quote.

`(...)*`           Any number of repetitions of text possibly containing text in double quotes.

`Ending$`      The pattern at the very ending of the text.

Comment: No, I'm sorry for bit unclear question. I'll edit it. It was count of double quotes.... It's edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

(Edited to allow for new lines in text)

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  string l_input1 = "match \"text\" with \r\n even \"quotes\"";
  string l_input2 = "unmatch \"text\" with \r\n uneven quotes\"";

  string l_pattern = @"^(?>([^""]*?((?<QUOTE>"")[^""]*(?<-QUOTE>"")?))*)$(?(QUOTE)(?!))";

  bool l_isMatch1 = Regex.IsMatch( l_input1, l_pattern );
  bool l_isMatch2 = Regex.IsMatch( l_input2, l_pattern );

  Console.WriteLine( l_isMatch1 );
  Console.WriteLine( l_isMatch2 );

  Console.ReadKey( true );

}
```

Explanation:

```
^(?>([^"]*?((?<QUOTE>")[^"]*(?<-QUOTE>")?))*)$(?(QUOTE)(?!))
```

This will attempt to match from the beginning of the input (^) to the end ($) to prevent it from just ignoring the text after the final odd double quote.

The basic idea is to toggle the QUOTE named group stack between 1 match and 0 matches. So, the regex will start by matching 0 or more non-double quote characters ([^"]*?). If it finds a double quote, it adds it to a named group (named "QUOTE") stack and continues matching 0 or more non-double quote characters. If it finds a second double quote, it removes the last match added to the "QUOTE" stack (so the stack will contain 0 matches) and then repeats back to the start.

After the end of the string, there is a conditional grouper. The condition is that if 1 or more matches have been added to the named group "QUOTES", then perform a zero-length negative lookahead (which will always cause a regex to fail). This will ensure that, if the second quote was not found (thus clearing the "QUOTES" stack), then the entire regex fails.

EDIT:

If you actually want to capture the quoted text, use this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  string l_input1 = "match \"text\" with \r\n even \"quotes\"";
  string l_input2 = "unmatch \"text\" with \r\n uneven quotes\"";

  string l_pattern = @"^(?>([^""]*?(?<QUOTED_TEXT>(?<QUOTE>"")[^""]*(?<-QUOTE>"")?))*)$(?(QUOTE)(?!))";

  Match l_match1 = Regex.Match( l_input1, l_pattern );
  Match l_match2 = Regex.Match( l_input2, l_pattern );

  Console.WriteLine( l_match1.Success );
  foreach ( Capture l_quotedText in l_match1.Groups["QUOTED_TEXT"].Captures ) {
    Console.WriteLine( l_quotedText.Value );
  }

  Console.WriteLine( l_match2.Success );

  Console.ReadKey( true );

}
```

}

Comment: The `Multiline` modifier is incorrect.  All it does is change the meaning of the anchors (`^`  and `$`) so they match the beginning and end of any *line*, not just the beginning and end of the input.